# Rails 5.1.6 - Stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stack-overflow

I'm using Rails 5.1.6 with Puma and MySQL.
I have the below code in a Rails controller:

```
class ScansController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_device, only: %i[index new create]
  .
  .
  .
  def create
    @scan = @device.scans.create(scan_params)
    flash[:notice] = t('.success') if @scan.save
    respond_with @scan.device, @scan
  end
  .
  .
  .
  private

  def find_device
    @device = Device.find params[:device_id]
  end

  def scan_params
    params.require(:scan).permit(:photo, :device_id, :reading, :reading_date)
  end
end
```

And when I send a POST request to this URL the below happens:

```
Started POST "/en/devices/1/scans" for 81.0.89.20 at 2018-04-03 09:39:19 +0000
09:39:19 web.1    | Processing by ScansController#create as HTML
09:39:19 web.1    |   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"QFdUs2thGPzJMbcWfApbattFMvnIEfzN1swrVGnbOTx7XbjY0Y3A8PLI1bRxqyBv6xIk9D2t13bfLPAqdSIyzQ==", "scan"=>{"reading_date"=>"2018-04-03T11:39:11", "reading"=>"6"}, "button"=>"", "locale"=>"en", "device_id"=>"1"}
09:39:19 web.1    |   User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
09:39:19 web.1    |   Device Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `devices`.* FROM `devices` WHERE `devices`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
09:39:19 web.1    |    (0.6ms)  BEGIN
09:39:19 web.1    |    (0.7ms)  ROLLBACK
09:39:19 web.1    | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 33ms (ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
09:39:19 web.1    | 
09:39:19 web.1    | 
09:39:19 web.1    |   
09:39:19 web.1    | SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
09:39:19 web.1    |   
09:39:19 web.1    | app/controllers/scans_controller.rb:35:in `create'
```

Now, line 35 is this line:`@scan = @device.scans.create(scan_params)`

and this was working well in Rails 4, but now that I migrated to Rails 5.1.6 it produces this behaviior even in my integration tests.
I hav no clue what could be the reason for this behavior. Does anyone sees something my eyes avoided for the last one or two weeks?
Thanx in advance.

The models:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end

class Scan < ApplicationRecord
  .
  .
  belongs_to :device, inverse_of: :scans
  validates_attachment(
    :photo,
    content_type: {
      content_type: [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/gif',
        'image/png',
        'image/tiff'
      ]
    }
  )
  with_options unless: @photo.present? do
    validates :reading, presence: true
    validates :reading, numericality: true
    validates :reading_date, presence: true
  end
  .
end

class Device < ApplicationRecord
  .
  .
  has_many :scans, inverse_of: :device, dependent: :restrict_with_error
  validates :unit, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :serial, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :owner, presence: true
  validates :precision, numericality: {
    only_integer: true,
    greater_than_or_equal_to: 0
  }, allow_nil: true
  . 
  .
end
```

The Full stack trace looks like this:

```
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
activemodel (5.1.6) lib/active_model/validations.rb:405:in `run_validations!'
activemodel (5.1.6) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:114:in `block in run_validations!'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
activemodel (5.1.6) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:114:in `run_validations!'
activemodel (5.1.6) lib/active_model/validations.rb:335:in `valid?'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/validations.rb:65:in `valid?'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:422:in `block in inverted_lambda'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:177:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:177:in `each'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:177:in `all?'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:177:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `block in invoke_before'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `each'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `invoke_before'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:130:in `run_callbacks'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
activemodel (5.1.6) lib/active_model/validations.rb:405:in `run_validations!'
activemodel (5.1.6) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:114:in `block in run_validations!'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
activemodel (5.1.6) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:114:in `run_validations!'
activemodel (5.1.6) lib/active_model/validations.rb:335:in `valid?'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/validations.rb:65:in `valid?'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/validations.rb:82:in `perform_validations'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/validations.rb:44:in `save'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:35:in `save'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:308:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:384:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:233:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:210:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:381:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:308:in `block in save'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:307:in `save'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:42:in `save'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_record_prepend.rb:16:in `block in save'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/transaction.rb:917:in `with_database_metric_name'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent.rb:618:in `with_database_metric_name'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_record_prepend.rb:15:in `save'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:371:in `insert_record'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:34:in `insert_record'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:360:in `block (2 levels) in _create_record'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:447:in `replace_on_target'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:281:in `add_to_target'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:358:in `block in _create_record'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:129:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:235:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:194:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:191:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:235:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:210:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:128:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:357:in `_create_record'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:121:in `_create_record'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:196:in `create'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:347:in `create'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:108:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:64:in `use_zone'
browser-timezone-rails (1.0.1) lib/browser-timezone-rails.rb:15:in `set_time_zone'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:844:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:in `traced_call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:32:in `traced_call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
rollbar (2.15.5) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:24:in `block in call'
rollbar (2.15.5) lib/rollbar.rb:145:in `scoped'
rollbar (2.15.5) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:22:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
rollbar (2.15.5) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb:22:in `call_with_rollbar'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
request_store (1.4.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
rack-rewrite (1.5.1) lib/rack/rewrite.rb:24:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (5.0.0.342) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:92:in `call'
puma (3.11.3) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
puma (3.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
puma (3.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
puma (3.11.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

This is the part which is repeating in the stack trace:

> activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:422:in 'block in inverted_lambda'
>
> activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:177:in 'block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
>
> activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:177:in 'each'
>
> activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:177:in 'all?'
>
> activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:177:in 'block in halting_and_conditional'
>
> activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in 'block in invoke_before'
>
> activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in 'each'
>
> activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in 'invoke_before'
>
> activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:130:in 'run_callbacks'
>
> activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in '_run_validate_callbacks'
>
> activemodel (5.1.6) lib/active_model/validations.rb:405:in 'run_validations!'
>
> activemodel (5.1.6) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:114:in 'block in run_validations!'
>
> activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in 'run_callbacks'
>
> activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in '_run_validation_callbacks'
>
> activemodel (5.1.6) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:114:in 'run_validations!'
>
> activemodel (5.1.6) lib/active_model/validations.rb:335:in 'valid?'
>
> activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/validations.rb:65:in 'valid?'

Comment: Hi @Antronin, Could you show the `validation` section the 2 models?

Comment: I added them, please check when you have some time. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution, although I don't exactly understand why it was working till now.
Originally there was the below validation in the Scan model (as I posted earlier):

```
  with_options unless: @photo.present? do
    validates :reading, presence: true
    validates :reading, numericality: true
    validates :reading_date, presence: true
  end
```

In irb I managed to localize the error to this validation part. After refactoring the `@photo.present?` to a new method and calling that method in the validation, the problem is solved:

```
  with_options unless: :has_photo? do
    validates :reading, presence: true
    validates :reading, numericality: true
    validates :reading_date, presence: true
  end

  def has_photo?
    @photo.present?
  end
```

Comment: Hi @Antronin, Sorry for replying late. Do you want me explain anymore?

Answer (score 0):

It's a race condition.
I think you can only have 1 inverse_of since scan will call device and vice versa.

Comment: By removing the "inverse_of" statements nothing has changed. It seems it isn't related to that, as I removed it from both ends of the association and the behavior stayed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates):

`:unless` option:

> Specifies a method, proc or string to call to determine if
>   the validation should not occur. The method, proc
>   or string should return or evaluate to a true or false value.

But, your model `Scan` have `unless: @photo.present?`:

```
with_options unless: @photo.present? do
  validates :reading, presence: true
  ...
end
```

That will lead to unexpected exceptions. In order to solve this issue, we should use any one of them below:

```
# Option 1:
with_options unless: proc { |scan| scan.photo.present? }

# Option 2:
with_options unless: 'photo.present?'

# Option 3:
with_options unless: :photo_present?

private

def photo_present?
  photo.present?
end
```

Comment: Thanx, this is clear now. What I don't understand is the stack overflow I experienced.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I encountered a similar error due to bad naming, please consider checking if the names could interfere with something inside of rails